How to compute the vector $\mathbf{v}$ in verifiable encryption scheme?

In the subsection 6.3 of Lattice-Based Zero-Knowledge Proofs and Applications: Shorter, Simpler, and More General, if the module p of encryption scheme is co-prime to the module q of commitment scheme, how to compute the vector $\mathbf{v}$?

Using equation (74)

In the encryption scheme, the ciphertext is $\begin{bmatrix}
t_0\
t_1
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{A}\
\mathbf{b}^T
\end{bmatrix}\mathbf{r}+
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{0}\
\lfloor p/2\rceil m
\end{bmatrix}$. If we use equation (74) to compute $\mathbf{v}$, the result is a zero vector, which is conflicting to the context.

Note that encryption as defined in (72) is performed over $\mathcal R_p$, equation (73) is over $\mathcal R$ with naive lifting and equation (74) is over $\mathcal R_q$.

Yes, (72) is performed over $\mathcal{R}{p}$, the zero-knowledge proof is performed in $\mathcal{R}{q}$, so we need a transformation to obtain (74).

The terms of (73 are derived from the terms in (72) by naive lifting (with implicit definition of $\mathbf v$; the terms in (74) are derived from the terms in (73) by reduction mod $q$.

To compute the term $\mathbf{v}$, we first compute the right of (73) using the schoolbook method without the module operation, and regard the result as $\mathbf{t}^\prime$. Then we compute $\mathbf{v} = (\mathbf{t}^\prime-\mathbf{v})/q$.
